# get_shipping_methods() return empty rate

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I used the code below to get the shipping method but it returned an empty rate:

```
$woocommerce->shipping()->load_shipping_methods($package);
$shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping()->get_shipping_methods();
```

How can I get the shipping methods with calculated cost for the order?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer my question

```
$woocommerce->shipping()->calculate_shipping_for_package($package);
$shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping()->get_shipping_methods();
```

It was fill rate And calculate the cost

Comment: More code to get active shipping methods :

foreach ($shipping_methods as $key => $shipping_method) {
if ($shipping_method->enabled != 'yes') {
unset($shipping_methods[$key]);
}

Comment: Hi, what to pass here as a $package?